# Average angle between x and Ax?

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-coordinates

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a fixed positive definite matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The cosine of angle between $x$ and $Ax$ is given by
$$
\frac{x^T Ax}{\|x\|\|Ax\|}.
$$ 
I want to know what the average value of the above expression is when $x$ is uniformly distributed on unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Diagonalizing $A$ and some algebraic manipulation, one can show that the answer is equal to
$$
\int_{\alpha_1^2+\cdots+\alpha_n^2=1} \frac{\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i^2}{\sqrt{\sum\lambda_i^2\alpha_i^2}}\,d \alpha_1\cdots d\alpha_n, 
$$
where $\lambda_i$, for $1\leq i\leq n$, are the eigenvalues of $A$. However, I do not know how to calculate the above integral.

Comment: What does it mean: "uniformly distributed in $\mathbb{R}^n$"?!

Comment: "The angle between $x$ and $Ax$" The **cosine** of the angle between them is given by that expression.

Comment: Maybe you mean "uniformly distributed on the unit sphere"?

Comment: You write anything and you ignore comments... Moreover, to obtain  the average of the cosinus of angle, you must divide your formula by the measure of $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @GReyes Thanks, I modified it.